# How to show all elements on page load (currently being filtered out) - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I have a page that shows a grid of images with a title, description, author, and some other additional information all pulled in from my SQL table (data is `marketplaceData`).

I have built a search bar for the page to filter through the grid of images, and it works great. As soon as I start typing, the filtered images show. When I backspace until my input value is `""`, all the images in the grid show.

My issue is that on page load (or when I refresh), the grid is empty and all the images have been filtered out. What do I need to change/add in order to make sure the full grid of images is not filtered to begin with? Many thanks in advance.

```
const MarketplaceGrid = ({ classes }) => {

  const marketplaceData = useSelector(
      (state) => state.marketplace.marketplaceData
    );

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState(marketplaceData);


  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("hi from onChange", event.target.value)
    setSearch(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value !== "") {
       setFilteredResults(marketplaceData.filter(item => item.alg_name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) || 
       item.alg_description.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) ||
       item.author.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) ||
       item.alg_type.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
       ))
      }
    else {
      setFilteredResults(marketplaceData)
    }
    };
    
    return (
      <main className={classes.content} >

      <div>{JSON.stringify(marketplaceData["alg_name"])}</div>

      <div className={classes}>
            <div className={classes}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search by Model Name"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={search}
            />
          </div>

        <GridContainer>
          {filteredResults.map((marketplace, i) => (
            <GridItem xs={1} sm={2} md={3} key={i}>
              <MarketplaceCard {...marketplace} classes={classes} alg_classes={marketplace.classes}
                //pass down all properties of marketplace as props
              />
            </GridItem>
          ))}
       
        </GridContainer>
        </main>
    );
  };
  
  export default MarketplaceGrid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your filter logic into a `useEffect` with the search dependency.

Then, just set the search in your `handleChange` method.

This way your handleChange is only updating the search and this causes a side-effect of filtering the results. Also, this effect will run the first time the component loads.

```
  const marketplaceData = useSelector(
    (state) => state.marketplace.marketplaceData
  );

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState(marketplaceData);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("hi from onChange", event.target.value);
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (search !== "") {
      setFilteredResults(
        marketplaceData.filter(
          (item) =>
            item.alg_name
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.alg_description
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.author
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.alg_type
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    } else {
      setFilteredResults(marketplaceData);
    }
  }, [search, setFilteredResults, marketplaceData]);
```

Comment: I'm getting a compilation error because `'event' is deprecated`. How did you work around that? I tried `useEffect((event) => ` but that had issues with setFilteredResults for an undefined target

Comment: Sorry, typo in the code. You need to change the `event.target.value.toLowerCase()` to `search.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @Henrik Awesome, happy to help.